# Add a color on top of the background image,

Tags: html, css

Trying to create this site and fairly new to html, trying to find ways of just adding a simple bar across or over
my background, without it repeating with the background image, i just want the thing at the top
like a background to the nav bar,

kinda tried just adding the enter code herecolor to the background img on photoshop, but of course it repeats that, which aint what im looking for

heres my stuff some helps appreciated.

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
  position:absolute;
  

}

/* Navbar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}



/* Navbar links on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
      padding-top:50px;
    
  }
}
<link href=CrimsonRainer Site/CrimsonRainer.css" rel="stylesheet" type=text/css> 

* {
  margin: 50;
  padding-top: 50;
}

html,

body {
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #021027;
  background-image:url("sky.jpg");
  background-repeat:repeat;
  background-size:cover;  
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first. 
Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
After you have done that, edit your question to meet those guidelines and to include 
a [minimal, reproduciable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element can have several background images, and they each can be set to repeat or not individually. One of the images could be a linear-gradient with your color in it.

The background images are 'drawn' in reverse order, that is, the one that is listed first will overwrite the next one listed and so on.

Not knowing exactly what you want here is a little example where the div has a repeating background image but at the top is a colored bar which is not repeated.

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(cyan, cyan), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300);
  background-size: 100% 20%, 20% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, repeat repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thats pretty useful thanks! that got me closer, the only thing now would be adjusting the height of the bar, by some px, wouldnt the background size, effect both though?, As u mentioned its basically a colored bar, which doesnt repeat over a background img which repeats,

Comment: You can define the height of the bar background in px if you want (though of course not so responsive as doing it in % terms - I just used 100% 20% as an example).

Comment: Ah, thats good to know thanks for that, that cracked it, ill remember %'s :D